# Fix layout of component in package

Tags: plantuml

I was not able to figure out how to fix the layout of my plantuml diagram.
There seems to be no skin parameter for padding of packages or margin of components. Any ideas?

[image]

```
@startuml

mainframe Old

component GUI {  
    component "IBM ILOG Views" {
    }
}

@enduml
```

Comment: `mainframe` was added in v1.2019.1(9 Feb, 2019) but not really documented at the time. It looks like styling for `mainframe` was not fixed until V1.2022.12 (23 Oct, 2022). Sources: https://forum.plantuml.net/16588/style-allow-all-style-for-mainframe and https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/issues/148#issuecomment-472490973

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used `mainframe` (not sure where that comes from). I just know `frame` in which one nests other elements:

```
@startuml
frame Old {
    component GUI {  
        component "IBM ILOG Views" {
        }
    }
}
@enduml
```

[image: Frame with components]